# Spark Dataframe cartesion product by columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is there any way to do a column-wise Cartesian join in Spark?

For example, given a dataframe

```
+------+------+------+
|col_a |col_b |col_c |
+------+------+------+
|0     |10    |100   |
|0     |20    |200   |
|0     |30    |300   |
|0     |40    |400   |
+------+------+------+
```

The result is a group of dataframes

```
+------+------+
|col_a |col_b |
+------+------+
|0     |10    |
|0     |20    |
|0     |30    |
|0     |40    |
+------+------+

+------+------+
|col_a |col_c |
+------+------+
|0     |100   |
|0     |200   |
|0     |300   |
|0     |400   |
+------+------+

+------+------+
|col_b |col_c |
+------+------+
|10    |100   |
|20    |200   |
|30    |300   |
|40    |400   |
+------+------+
```

I'm aware that it can be done in code (by creating a list of column name tuples and selecting through iteration), but I'd like to leverage spark parallelism if possible by calling the same UDF on all of them, ie. something similar to groupby().apply(). Is this possible?

I'm using Spark 3.1.1 with pyspark

Thanks

Comment: But select is not an operation where you leverage parallelism. It just "references" the column from the parent df, no real (parallel) computing is performed. I say it's completely fine to select through iteration.

Comment: I need  to apply a UDF to all of them in the following step, that's where the parrelism would come in (added this part to the question)

Comment: Using a UDF means "no parallelism". That's the worst thing to do performance-wise.

Comment: I see what your mean. Would a better approach be to recombine (stack?) the result dfs and then use groupby()?

Comment: I have no idea. I do not know what you are trying to do. Currently, it is a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). I'm just helping you with a solution you imagined would be the good one. If you explain your actual complete business need, there is probably a better solution indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue has no connection with the Spark parallelism. It is not a cartesion product, it is simply a combination of columns.
A `select` is a simple spark transformation, it will be imediate to excute and you just need python for that :

```py
from itertools import combinations


df_list = [df.select(*cols) for cols in combinations(df.columns, 2)]
```

Result is :

```
df_list 
[DataFrame[col_a: bigint, col_b: bigint],
 DataFrame[col_a: bigint, col_c: bigint],
 DataFrame[col_b: bigint, col_c: bigint]]
```

Comment: Assuming they can all be made to have the same schema, can a UDF be applied in parallel to all the dataframes in that list?

Comment: @AvishaiFuss of course. when I do `df.select(*cols)`, just replace it with the UDF : `df.select(my_udf(*cols))`.